# Wiki or CMS to store cards (CCG/Sports/...etc)

Tags: cms, wiki, nosql

A friend wants to create an online database that contains every card that exists in the world. This includes everything from magic the gathering, sports cards to normal (52) cards, Risk cards etc. I want to help and although for me it seems impossible to have every card, we could have a lot.

I'm now wondering what would be the best way to store the cards. Is there something like a Wiki, but with more structured data? From one viewpoint a Wiki seems suitable since we don't have to worry about different data-models for different games (we just enter the cards as free text), but from another viewpoint something like MongoDB seems more suitable, as it's better to have the data structured and it will be possible for visitors to filter cards on properties of a game. I think there are already too many different games to manually program a View (as in mVc) for each game. Is there something in between MongoDB and a Wiki?

Another idea would be to have a "CMS" with a no-sql database where all cards are in the same table, where you can manually, without programming, create views (i.e. frontend layout) that are selected based on certain properties of each item. For example, you could create a "Mtg Creature View". And when the card- table contains something like

```
{ "card-type": "ccg",
  "game": "Magic the gathering",
  "expansion": "Ice Age",
  "type": "Creature",
  "Power": "7"
  "Thoughness": "6" }
```

then that view will be applied because the "game" and the "type" are a match. Does something like that exist or is it possible to modify an existing framework for this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you install Wikibase on your server:

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase

It is very structured, so you can set up the properties (name, level, origin, image, etc) that each card can have.

In the wiki spirit, it is easy to edit by anyone you give permission to.

Unlike Wikipedia/etc there is no wikicode, you can not do syntax mistake.

Test item on wikidata.org, an instance of Wikibase: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4115189

Screenshot of the Wikibase instance hosted at wikidata.org:

[image]